# Choosing presidence with border hover

Tags: css

I have a simple nav list. Typical set up, where the active page li item has the id "active".
I want to be able to keep the active page as a link, have a solid border underneath, but have a dashed border on the li items without the "active" id.

How can I achieve this without having the active tag being overwritten with the dashed border-bottom?

Here's the code for the list:

```
<div id="nav_bar">
  <ul id="nav_list">
    <li id="active"><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Design</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Photography</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

[jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/FaESR/)

Comment: Can you show us what you have so far that is not working?

Comment: Can you also provide the CSS? Better yet, a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) example?

Comment: here's what I was trying that didn't work http://jsfiddle.net/FaESR/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since borders are already being applied to each `a`, make the `:hover` only apply to `li` that are not `#active` by using [`:not()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3anot).

Change:

```
#nav_list li a:hover{
    border-bottom:1px dashed #666;
}

#active a{
    border-bottom:1px solid #666;
}

#nav_list li#active a:hover{
    border-bottom:1px dashed #666;
}
```

To:

```
li#active a{
    border-bottom:1px solid #666;
}

#nav_list > li:not(#active) a:hover{
    border-bottom:1px dashed #666;
}
```

DEMO:
http://jsfiddle.net/FaESR/1/

*NOTE*: Make sure to use `class` instead of `id` if you plan on having *more than one* instance of `#active`, since `id` ***must*** be unique!

Happy coding!

Comment: thanks! I was wondering if there was some way of excluding tags